# Webpage make background stay the same until scroll down far enough

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure if this is possible, I am trying to put a novel type document on a html page, I would like the background to stay the same for each chapter, but once they scroll down far enough to the next chapter, the background needs to change to that chapter's (the change could be instant or smoothly doesn't matter)

Any hints?

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course using the jQuery library...

in your header or footer you include the jquery library...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then you include this chunk after the script above...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        bg.init();

        $(window).scroll(function(){        
                bg.updateBG();
        });
    });

    var bg = {
    current_image: 'chapter_1',
    offsets: new Array(),
    init: function(){
        $('.chapter').each(function(){
            bg.offsets.push($(this).height());
        });
    },
    updateBG: function(){
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        var total = bg.offsets.length;
        var current_image;
        var chapter = 1;

        for(var i = 0; i < total; i ++)
        {
            if(offset > bg.offsets[i])
            {
                chapter = (i + 1);
                current_image = 'chapter_' + chapter;
                // this will leave the last image overwrite as the current image
            }
        }

        if(current_image != bg.current_image)
             {
                  $('body').css('background', 'url(/path-to-image/' + current_image + '.jpg) no-repeat center center');
                  bg.current_image = current_image;

                  // only update if a change is noticed
             }
        }
    };
        </script>
```

here is sample html to make sense of this convoluted JS...

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="chapter" id="chapter_1">
        some content
    </div>
    <div class="chapter" id="chapter_2">
        some content
    </div>
    <div class="chapter" id="chapter_3">
        some content
    </div>
</div>
```

Where your content is in the #container element, obviously. Also, update the path to the real image. There are smoother ways to transition, but you can decide how you want to do that then ask for specifics.

Also, the window height divided by 2 is so you swap images midway through the page at the bottom. I found it is smoother this way for the projects I used this on.

Comment: Sorry I'm a javascript newbie, should i be putting this in the <head></head>? Thanks!

Comment: you can put it there or before the closing body tag. Modern standards are moving to a footer js habit since it loads after the site content, but this wouldn't really affect much on light weight sites. I updated the answer to reflect the whole code in case you are not totally familiar

Comment: minitech makes a good point too. You may want to keep track of which element you're currently viewing so the background image changes back to the right chapter if the user scrolls up. I will update my answer again...

Comment: It is updated, but may likely need some balancing, specifically around the if(offset > bg.offsets[i]) line. But you will likely get results and will not be confused about how to get it to do what you want. It will just be some basic math at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `scrollTop()` to calculate the current view position via JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rpCEr/

Here's the same demo with a fading animation applied: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/rpCEr/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the current scroll position, the offset of the chapter elements, and change the background accordingly. (Note that this code isn't cross-browser - you'll need to make some changes for full IE compatibility)

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/9LYpA/